# How to write a decorator of async method that executes only on `Promise.resolve()`?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, tsc, typescript-decorator

This decorator will be dedicated to analytics that sends event when a Promise was successfully resolved.

```
class Foo {

  @LogEvent("success")
  async bar() {

    await someAction();

  }

}
```

I have read some articles on the Web and I guess I have to get a descriptor of a function (since transpiled methods of classes are functions), then I need to classify if this is an async one or not... There are some possible troubles with Typescript because it marks some async methods non-async and it also depends on which standart of EcmaScript it is targeted - so many conditions when it can fail! There is certainly a way to write a stable solution.

Your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```js
function LogEvent(param: string) {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(... params: any[])=> Promise<any>>) => {
        let oldFunc = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = async function (){
            const result = await oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
            await analytics.send(param);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

inspired on: [Typescript, decorate async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512544/typescript-decorate-async-function)

in this way, the Decorator only works on async methods, so I don't know about what you said that typescript only marks some async methods non-async, got any source for that?